# Json validator for node

Tags: node.js, json, schema

I would like to use a framework that validates a given json according to some criterias, as like as:

- optional fields.
- mandatory fields.
- reject jsons that has non specified fields from a schema.

Is there some kind of framework for node to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know about framework but ajv is a nice library for that
https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Answer (score 1):

There is a light-weight [ts-interface-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-interface-checker) which works nicely with TypeScript and [ts-interface-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-interface-builder), but can also be used standalone.

For example:

```
const t = require("ts-interface-checker");

const {Square} = t.createCheckers({
  Square: t.iface([], {
    "size": "number",
    "color": t.opt("string"),
  })
});

Square.check({size: 1});                  // OK
Square.check({size: 1, color: "green"});  // OK
Square.check({color: "green"});           // Fails with "value.size is missing"
Square.check({size: 4, color: 5});        // Fails with "value.color is not a string"
Square.strictCheck({size: 4, spin: 5});   // Fails with "value.spin is extraneuous"
```